# Why drawing line on canvas doesn't appear?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm using a html 5 to draw a line on canvas with a button.

**Does anybody know why?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <body onload="">

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="200" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
<button name="draw" onclick="drawLine()">Draw Line</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="canvashtml5.js" ></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**darwLine function is on the external javascript as canvasHtml5.js:**

```
function drawLine(){
   var canvas = document.getElementById(myCanvas);
   var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
   context.moveTo(0,0);
   context.lineTo(300,150);
   context.stroke();
}
myCanvas
{
   var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
   var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
   ctx.fillStyle="#FFFF00";
   ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
}
```

Comment: Forgot the quotes? `var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas")` would work http://jsfiddle.net/MsRcH/1/

Comment: What does your `myCanvas` function return? It should return string.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to put myCanvas to quot like this: "myCanvas".

this var canvas = document.getElementById(myCanvas); must be like  `var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");`

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

Add an event listener to your button like so:

```
document.getElementById('drawLineBtn').addEventListener('click', drawLine, false);
```

This will cut down on your work in the future. See http://jsfiddle.net/kbXAN/23/